# Automatically copy new data to first spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I need help with the following problem. I have a file with two tables. In table 1 are data about different people (name, team and size), in table 2 only the name and team. Is it possible that if I enter in table a new name with team, that then in table 1 is automatically created a new column, with the name in row 1 and the team in row 2, inserting the person should be according to the team. If he is in team B, then he should be copied automatically behind to the last person of the corresponding team. For example, in the file the new name is Mike, he is in team B. Now the name should be copied automatically to F1 and the team to F2, all this without changing the columns of the other persons. Is this possible?

I have uploaded the file to Sheets:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17hm8ekjp4yULZSTdFsxKbXC7fNj1EGo6eSpAgjGnjtg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You could use the sort and transpose function

```
=transpose((sort(Tabellenblatt2!A2:B,2,True)))
```

If you enter this formula into cell A1 of Tabellenblatt1, this will then populate a transpossed sorted table of information.

If you remove people from Tabellenblatt2 it will remove them from Tabellenblatt1, but this should give you a transposed table.

The transpose element is taking the A2:B range and turning it from Vertical to Horizontal.

The sort element is taking the data and sorting it by the 2nd value, in an ascending order

Comment: Thanks it kinda worked. Only work if i use "sort(Tabellenblatt2!A2:B9" f.e. But now comes the tricky part. How do I make it so that the names are automatically sorted by team, as already created, but the size corresponds to the matching people, so that the correct size is also under the name and then bsp. under Mike is nothing, but under the rest it does.

Comment: A formula based process such as I have provided wouldnt do the movement that you require. It would need some form of Visual Basic (VB) script to allow this to be undertaken. You may be best to edit your question and add VB as a additional tag to identify the issue to experts in that area